# How to define different struct to single variable

Tags: c

I am declaring one variable based on the condition:

```
if(abc == 2)
{
price* x;
    x = (price *)malloc(2 * sizeof(price*));
}
else if(abc == 3)
{
store* x;
    x = (store *)malloc(2 * sizeof(store*));
}

// x is getting used in other function
xyz(&x);
```

while compile, it is throwing error: error: 'x' was not declared in this scope. I understand that, since x is not defined in the function scope, it is throwing error.

I tried to declare void* x, but that also didn't work. Is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: Why didn't `void *` work? It will work if you do it correctly. What problems you face when using `void *`?

Comment: Thanks, But it is throwing error if I am using x like this: xyz(&x[0]); error: pointer of type 'void ' used in arithmetic , error: 'void' is not a pointer-to-object type

Comment: As the error says `void *` is an incomplete type. Pass `xyz(x)` instead of indexing it. I am wondering what `xyz()` does with `x` without knowing the type of `x`.

Comment: above code , is a sample piece of code. I didn't posted the actual code. In xyz, we need to pass the parameter like &x[0] . As of now, I have two different function for each struct , which is working fine. I am trying to refactor the code, by adding this if condition.

Comment: `xyz` needs to cast it back to `price*` or `store*` before it can index it. And it needs some way to know which one it points to.

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare `x` before the `if`. The problem is the scope of the variable not the type!

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want

```
void* x = 0;

if(abc == 2)
{
    x = (price *)malloc(2 * sizeof(price*));
}
else if(abc == 3)
{
    x = (store *)malloc(2 * sizeof(store*));
}
```

btw, size or type seems suspicious in malloc line.

I think you want

```
x = (price **)malloc(2 * sizeof(price*));
```

or

```
x = (price *)malloc(2 * sizeof(price));
```

Comment: Thanks, But it is throwing error if I am using x like this:  xyz(&x[0]); error: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic , error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

Comment: @user1138143: What is `xyz` ? Is `xyz(x)` sufficient ?